# PostgreSQL - construct well formated json object from query

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgresql table which looks like this :

```
ID   CURRENCY    PRICE
1    EUR         100
2    USD         90
```

I want to do a query that returns a JSON object formatted like this:
    {
      "EUR": 100,
      "USD": 90
    }

I succeeded by using json_object but I have to cast my integer values into TEXT.

```
SELECT json_object(
   array_agg(prices.currency),
   array_agg(cast(prices.price as text))
) FROM prices;
```

So if you have a better idea, I'm taking it ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json_object_agg()`:

```
with data (id, currency, price) as (
values
    (1, 'EUR', 100),
    (2, 'USD', 90)
)
select json_object_agg(currency, price)
from data;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for :)